# Hashmap with Streams in Java 8 Streams to collect value of Map

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, collectors

Let consider a hashmap

```
Map<Integer, List> id1 = new HashMap<Integer,List>();
```

I inserted some values into both hashmap.

For Example,

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

list1.add("r1");
list1.add("r4");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("r2");
list2.add("r5");

List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
list3.add("r3");
list3.add("r6");

id1.put(1,list1);
id1.put(2,list2);
id1.put(3,list3);
id1.put(10,list2);
id1.put(15,list3);
```

Q1)    Now I want to apply a filter condition on the key in hashmap and retrieve the corresponding value(List).

Eg: Here My query is key=1, and output should be 'list1'

I wrote

```
id1.entrySet().stream().filter( e -> e.getKey() == 1);
```

But I don't know how to retrieve as a list as output of this stream operation.

Q2)        Again I want to apply a filter condition on the key in hashmap and retrieve the corresponding list of lists.

Eg:  Here My query is key=1%(i.e key can be 1,10,15), and output should be 'list1','list2','list3'(list of lists).

Comment: Don’t use half-baked Generic types. Most probably, your map ought to be `Map<Integer, List<String>>` rather than `Map<Integer, List>`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you are sure you are going to get at most a single element that passed the filter (which is guaranteed by your filter), you can use `findFirst` :

```
Optional<List> o = id1.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .filter( e -> e.getKey() == 1)
                      .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                      .findFirst();
```

In the general case, if the filter may match multiple Lists, you can collect them to a List of Lists :

```
List<List> list = id1.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(.. some predicate...)
                     .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 48):

What you need to do is create a `Stream` out of the `Map`'s `.entrySet()`:

```
// Map<K, V> --> Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> --> Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>>
map.entrySet().stream()
```

From the on, you can `.filter()` over these entries. For instance:

```
// Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>> --> Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>>
.filter(entry -> entry.getKey() == 1)
```

And to obtain the values from it you `.map()`:

```
// Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>> --> Stream<V>
.map(Map.Entry::getValue)
```

Finally, you need to collect into a `List`:

```
// Stream<V> --> List<V>
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If you have only one entry, use this instead (NOTE: this code assumes that there is a value; otherwise, use `.orElse()`; see the [javadoc of `Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for more details):

```
// Stream<V> --> Optional<V> --> V
.findFirst().get()
```

Comment: @user2336315 yes, this code assumes that the value exists; OP isn't very clear about this. Ahwell

Answer (score 5):

For your Q2, there are already answers to your question. For your Q1, and more generally when you know that the key's filtering should give a unique value, there's no need to use Streams at all.

Just use `get` or `getOrDefault`, i.e:

```
List<String> list1 = id1.getOrDefault(1, Collections.emptyList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this

```
public Map<Boolean, List<Student>> getpartitionMap(List<Student> studentsList) {

    List<Predicate<Student>> allPredicates = getAllPredicates();
    Predicate<Student> compositePredicate =  allPredicates.stream()
                             .reduce(w -> true, Predicate::and)
     Map<Boolean, List<Student>> studentsMap= studentsList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(compositePredicate));
    return studentsMap;
}

public List<Student> getValidStudentsList(Map<Boolean, List<Student>> studentsMap) throws Exception {

    List<Student> validStudentsList =  studentsMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .filter(p -> p.getKey() == Boolean.TRUE)
             .flatMap(p -> p.getValue().stream())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return validStudentsList;
}

public List<Student> getInValidStudentsList(Map<Boolean, List<Student>> studentsMap) throws Exception {

    List<Student> invalidStudentsList = 
             partionedByPredicate.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .filter(p -> p.getKey() == Boolean.FALSE)
             .flatMap(p -> p.getValue().stream())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return invalidStudentsList;

}
```

With `flatMap` you will get just `List<Student>` instead of `List<List<Student>>`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using keySet-

```java
id1.keySet().stream()
        .filter(x -> x == 1)
        .map(x -> id1.get(x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

why all that !!!

> List list1 = id1.get(1);

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
    hashmap.put(1, "a");
    hashmap.put(2, "b");
    List<String> collect = hashmap.keySet().stream()
                            .map(k -> "key=" + k + " value=" + hashmap.get(k))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the sample is oversimplified, but you don't need the Java stream API here. Just use the Map directly.

```
 List<String> list1 = id1.get(1); // this will return the list from your map
```